# Client country name shows null

Tags: asp.net

I have used the following code to get the country name of the client. For that I used 
http://ipaddressextensions.codeplex.com/ dll library. But when run my code the country did not 
show any value. I have also used public IP. So how can I get my country name?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using WorldDomination.Net;

public static string GetLocation()
    {
        string userHostIpAddress = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
        string country = String.Empty;
        string iso3166TwoLetterCode = String.Empty;

        IPAddress ipAddress;

        if (IPAddress.TryParse(userHostIpAddress, out ipAddress))
        {
            country = ipAddress.Country(); // return value: UNITED STATES
            iso3166TwoLetterCode = ipAddress.Iso3166TwoLetterCode(); // return value: US
        }

        return country;
    }
```

Comment: i am not getting ipAddress.Country() this country method can you plz help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code uses an database from Webnet77 (according to their Codeplex site). Can they resolve your ip with their [online service](http://software77.net/geo-ip/multi-lookup/)? If so, update your database, the Codeplex site hasn't had a new release since 2008.

Comment: But if I assign my ip 203.76.115.10 (The IP address of the remote host making the request (or the proxy server)) to userHostIpAddress directly, I can get the correct location. Is there any way to retrieve it and set it into the userHostIpAddress?

Comment: Then check if the string contains extra data, perhaps newlines. Try calling .Trim() on the result from your WebClient.DownloadString.